# In Mutt, how to extract key from a S/MIME signed message to reply encrypted?

Tags: encryption, certificate, mutt

I have a certificate signed message in my inbox. The public certificate of the sender should be available there. How do I extract and use it to send back an encrypted message?

Note: I configured GPG and different profiles and Mutt is running absolutely fine with it, and I know the procedure that I request a public key from the sender for it. But with S/MIME certificates I seem to be lost.

Answer (score 2):

### Extracting Keys

If you have Mutt 1.5 or higher, run `extract-keys` (Bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> per default). See [the Mutt documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#reading-misc)); even though the online documentation mentions PGP only, it works for smime here as well: It will add the certificate in the mail to the database of `smime_key` and will ask you for an optional for that certificate. You can check that it has been added by running

```
smime_keys list
```

### Encrypting Messages

When sending an smime-encrypted mail, mutt picks the respective keys from the smime database. However: mutt saves the encrypted message to your record folder, i.e. you can't open it anymore. So you should either add yourself to the list of recipents (To:, Cc:, Bcc:), or you should enable `$fcc_clear`.
A patch fixing this has been posted on the [mutt-users mailing list 13 years ago](http://mutt-users.mutt.narkive.com/2qK1p7RO/encrypting-to-self-with-s-mime), but it doesn't seem to be merged. The patch is present in [neomutt](https://www.neomutt.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving us much info to go on, not even the OS you are using, so that you will have to bear with me if I am being a bit slow.

Mutt and S/MIME do not work together natively, so that you will have to do some work to get this going.

Second, which version of Mutt are you using? There is no support for S/MIME before 1.5. If you are using 1.4 or earlier, all I can say is to update your configuration.

Third, which OS are you on? I run Mutt and S/MIME on OpenBSD, and have used [this guide](http://equiraptor.com/smime_mutt_how-to.html) in the past, and it worked perfectly. If you are on Linux, I know (but I have no direct experience with it myself) that many people have found [this other guide](https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4091) very helpful.

Lastly, you should also be aware of the rather annoying fact that PGP/MIME messages, as produced by Mutt, are not supported by many other MUAs (Mail User Agents), so that you may have troubles reading messages by people using, for instance, Outlook or Outlook Express. You find this clearly stated in [this excellent Web page](http://mutt.blackfish.org.uk/cryptography/).

Like I said, this is just a first crack at your problem, you may perhaps check the references I gave you and see whether you have already done all of the configuring they suggest, or none at all.

Comment: Let's say I'm using Linux and the newest version of Mutt. But I don't see how that changes much... Thanks for your patience.